# Proof: $X$ is Hausdorff if and only if the diagonal $\Delta$ is closed in $X\times X$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Prove that $X$ is Hausdorff if and only if the diagonal $\Delta$ is closed in $X\times X$.

This exercise appeared on a previous exam in my course, and also in Munkres. Here's my attempt:

First I want to show the implication starting with assuming that $X$ is Hausdorff. Consider $(X\times X)\backslash \Delta$, then for any tuple $(x_1, x_2) \in (X\times X)\backslash \Delta$ we know $x_1\neq x_2$. Then there are neighbourhoods $U,V$ of $x_1,x_2$ respectively such that $U\cap V = \emptyset$. The set $U\times V$ is a basis element of $X\times X$ so it's in the product topology. So any tuple $(x_1, x_2) \in (X\times X)\backslash \Delta$ lies in an open set of $X\times X$, thus $(X\times X) \backslash\Delta$ is open which makes $\Delta$ closed in $X\times X$.

Now I assume that $\Delta$ is closed in $X\times X$. Then $(X\times X)\backslash\Delta$ is open in $X\times X$. Unless I'm mistaken, every open set $A\times B$ in $X\times X$ will be a subset of $(X\times X)\backslash\Delta$. Then $A\cap B = \emptyset$ because otherwise we would have $(x_1,x_1)\in A\times B \subseteq (X\times X)\backslash\Delta$ for some $x_1\in X$, which is a contradiction. Thus $X$ is Hausdorff.

I'm simply wondering if my argument is correct.

Comment: What is the diagonal $\Delta$? I haven't seen this kind of terminology

Comment: Is $X\times X\backslash \Delta=(X\times X)\backslash \Delta$?

Comment: It looks fine...almost. I'd prefer to see for any two different $\;x,y\in X\;$ two disjoint open sets containing them. This is not very clear from what you did.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi No duplicate: the asker here is asking about the correctness of his proof.

Comment: The first proof is correct, the second one isn't. You want to show that $X$ is Hausdorff, so start by picking $x \neq y \in X$. Then continue from there. Read the linked duplicate to see a correct proof.

Comment: @SiddharthBhat $\Delta:=\{(x,x)|x\in X \}$

Comment: @Joanpemo This question has been asked dozens of times. It's not necessary to add another one to the list.

Comment: @SiddharthBhat Is a common term in set theory and in topology. It is the set $$\Delta:=\left\{\,(a,b)\in X\times X\;/\;\;a=b\,\right\}$$

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Again: this particular question is **not** about the fact, but about how the asker did when trying to prove it. The question you linked ask about hte proof itself. Two different things.

Comment: @Joanpemo And *again*, this particular question has been asked dozens of time, and adding a new one to the site is useless or even actively harmful. I answered in the comments about the correctness of the proof, and now we can mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Auclair, can you put the tag proof-verification in your question? Thank you.

Comment: @Masacroso Done, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Can't you really understand that the asker is **not** asking how to prove the claim but in fact he's asking how is **his proof** ?? The question you linked asked about *the claim*: two different things!

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I think I corrected the second part of the proof. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Joanpemo I can understand that. Now calm yourself, please. There is little archival value in keeping this sort of proof-verification question, and it's better to direct future readers to the Q&A I linked.